# How to access a jsp page inside a folder under WEB-INF?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-inf

I'm learning about servlets and JSP and I try to make an app. The app is from this [page](https://o7planning.org/en/11071/create-a-simple-login-application-and-secure-pages-with-java-servlet-filter)

This is the structure of the app:

[image]

And I put all the JSP in WEB-INF:

[image]

When I try to run any jsp it's not working, I get this error: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found... Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

If I move the jsp in WebContent the app is working succesfully. But I want to keep the jsp in WEB-INF. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The whole point of putting them in WEB-INF is precisely to make it impossible to execute them. Because you want the request to go through a controller first, which would then forward to a JSP.

Comment: did you have any index.html. Which is point out in the web.xml?

Comment: How is the JSP page (in the `WEB-INF`) is being accessed? What is the code?

Comment: Post your servlet code, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems i got your problem. If you have `servlet class` write code to forward to jsp page like this. Because you have put your `jsp` page inside `WEB-INF/view`

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/homeView.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I resolved the problem...can I ask you something? Why did he override the isUserInRole() and getUserPrincipal() methods in UserRoleRequestWrapper class? He never used these methods...

Comment: Sorry man ! I cannot describe you because now i don't have such knowledge :(

Comment: @gaby, If the answer help you can you mark this one as important please ? So that it will help other !